# How to get current view from Page View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I understand that with my page control I can get the current view controller with "pageControl.currentPage".

Let's say I have a total of 3 view controllers, but the second view controller is being re-used.

So the order is [1stViewController, 2ndViewController, 2ndViewController]

From 2ndViewController, how can I determine if it's the 1st or 2nd index in the order?

I would like to be able to check in the viewDidLoad method before I update the UI of the view controller.

Comment: Create an initializer for your view controller and pass in an index when its created

Comment: how would I keep track of the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little project I threw together:
https://github.com/PJayRushton/PageViewControllerReferences

Basically I just created an array of view controllers used in the PageViewController DataSource and in the reused `ViewController` I check which view controller from the stored array it is.